# comparing two statements with one define variable java

Tags: java, compare

I wrote this code that random picks two cards from a deck, but I'm having trouble trying to get it to compare, I've run into some issues and want to work that out step by step but unsure how to compare both statements with only one defined variable?

```
    package question1;

    public class HouseOfCards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] SuitNames= {
                "Spades","Diamonds","Clubs","Hearts"
        };
        String [] CardNames= {
                "Ace","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"
        };
        String SuitName="hi",SuitName2="die";
        String CardName="hi", CardName2="die";
        for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
            int numCard=52;
            int randNum=(int)(Math.random() * numCard);
            int randNum2=(int)(Math.random() * numCard);
            int suitNum = randNum / 13;
            int cardNum = randNum % 13;
            int suitNum2 = randNum2 / 13;
            int cardNum2 = randNum2 % 13;
            SuitName = SuitNames[suitNum];
            CardName = CardNames[cardNum];
            SuitName2 = SuitNames [suitNum2];
            CardName2 = CardNames[cardNum2];
            System.out.println(CardName + " of " + SuitName);
        }
        if (CardName.equals(CardName2)){
            System.out.println("Same Rank");
        }

        else if (SuitName.equals(SuitName2)){
            System.out.println("Same Suit");
        }
    }    
}
```

i edited my code so that it displays if its the same rank between both random picked cards or same suit between random picked cards, but sometime it doesn't print the statement, why?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(CardName);` will not work if `CardNames` contains words like "Ace", "One" etc.

Comment: that is true, it was my trial and error moment when trying to code it, which is why I'm here to find out what could be done to fix it?

Comment: You need to have some way of looking up a numerical value for a card. You could use a HashMap, or a big switch or if/else statement, or you could use an enum to represent your card names.

Comment: parsing an integer from a string with no numbers will never work, ever

Comment: for an if/else statement for the comparison can i use the array i have and give the ace, one, two etc defined numbers or not. i just started learning about arrays and never used enum or big switch. also when comparing the suit they are all string but if statements are boolean which doesn't take strings

Comment: You also can't compare strings with `==`.

Comment: do i have to make an extra set of variable to compare to and when ever i try and use them i can't because the previous set is in the for loop and are closed once the for loop is closed?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  I see one loop that prints out some random card combinations, doing that 52 times.  Then you check for the same variable being equal to itself (after the commented out `parseInt()`).    I'm pretty confused.

Comment: ignoring the parse part of it, what i have done is take a for loop to run twice and print out two different cards from a deck, that part is fine so i closed the for loop as i should. now I'm trying to take those two random cards and compare them to see if the rank is the same or suit is the same or both? the only problem I've run into is to how to do. I'm thinking i have to use .equals but unsure since i only have one variable and i ran it twice, how do i compare do i need to run it with different variable then compare?

Comment: also when i do try and use the .equals it says the variable has not been initialized which makes me think that it isn't saving the value in the for loop and using it throughout the code, which I'm sure why, is it because i closed the for loop?

Comment: Did you mean "Suitname.equals(Suitname2)" instead of "Suitnames.equals(Suitname2)"?

Comment: i took your advice and it still keeps print Right???? I'm literally so confused??

Comment: Remove the semicolon in the if statement before System.out.println("Right");

Comment: i got it i needed to add brackets to the if statement

Comment: Now to do the rest of the if statement for both suit and rank, any know how to or just do a long if else statement???

Comment: i edited my code to see if i can compare both rank and suit and print statement but it does always print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class HouseOfCards {

public class HouseOfCards {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Spades=1;
    String [] suitNames= {
            "Spades","Diamonds","Clubs","Hearts"
    };
    String [] cardNames= {
            "Ace","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"
    };
    String card1="";
    String card2="";
    String suitName="";
    String cardName1="";
    String suitName2="";
    String cardName2="";
    int cardPosition1 = 0;
    int cardPosition2 = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=1; i++){
        int numCard=52;
        int randNum=(int)(Math.random() * numCard);
        int suitNum = randNum / 13;
        int cardNum = randNum % 13;
        if(i==0) {          
            suitName = suitNames[suitNum];
            cardName1 = cardNames[cardNum];
            card1 = cardName1+" of "+suitName;
        }
        else {
            suitName2 = suitNames[suitNum];
            cardName2 = cardNames[cardNum];
            card2 = cardName2+" of "+suitName2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(card1);
    System.out.println(card2);

    for (int i = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++) {
        if(cardName1.equals(cardNames[i])) {
            cardPosition1 = i;
        }
        if(cardName2.equals(cardNames[i])) {
            cardPosition2 = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cardPosition1);
    System.out.println(cardPosition2);
    if(cardPosition1>cardPosition2) {
        System.out.println("First card has bigger number");
    }
    else if (cardPosition1<cardPosition2) {
        System.out.println("Second card has bigger number");
    }
    else if (cardPosition1==cardPosition2) {
        System.out.println("Equal cards (probably different suites you can check it further)"); 
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: i like this code but i need to compare it to see if both card have same rank or suit or both? it works by saying which card is higher but not sure how it relates unless...

Comment: Well, it depends on a task, i'm really not that into cards but in String[] cardNames you have "Ace", "One". Not sure but isn't Ace actualy One? And for example, if you want to have Ace as the "strongest" card, just put it into the end of an array.